# Move downloaded files based on criteria

Tags: automation, sort

After downloading tv shows and movies I would like them to be automatically moved to two separate folders (named "tv shows" and "Movies"). 
I know there are a lot of programs that you can do this with on windows / osx but I am not sure about ubuntu. If there are not any for ubuntu would it be possible to make some sort of script myself?

The simplest criteria that I thought of would be to sort video files over 1 hour in length to the movies folder that way it would be fully automatic. I could always make a comment on the torrent such as "movie" and then read that with a script maybe?

Any tips would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I can imagine how to do this with inotify or a cronjob.

Answer (score 1):

This script should give you something to start off with. It does a decent job in moving videos (`.mp4` and `.mkv`, but you can add more) longer than 1 hr to `~/Downloads/Movies` and others to `~/Downloads/Shows`.

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(find -type f -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.mkv") #include anyother formats you want
while read -r line
do
    time="$(ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$line" 2>&1 | grep -Po '(?<=Duration: ).*(?=, start)'| cut -d : -f1)"
    if [[ $time -ge "1" ]] ; then
        if [ -d ~/Downloads/Movies ] ; then
            mv "$line" ~/Downloads/Movies
        else
            mkdir -p ~/Downloads/Movies
            mv "$line" ~/Downloads/Movies
        fi
    elif [[ $time == "00" ]] ; then
        if [ -d ~/Downloads/Shows ] ; then
            mv "$line" ~/Downloads/Shows
        else
            mkdir -p ~/Downloads/Shows
            mv "$line" ~/Downloads/Shows
        fi
    fi
done <<< "$files"
```

Additionally, if you are using torrent managers such as [Deluge](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins/Execute) or [Transmission](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Scripts) or others that supports running scripts on completion of torrents, you can provide this as the script to run. You may have to tweak it a bit, if needed.